# In guest OS, is it possible to re-use SSH keys of the host operating system?

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, vmware

I have a host Windows operating system and I have my ssh keys setup on my windows machine to access github and other resources. Now I installed a guest Linux OS using VMware player. Can I re-use the private keys on the windows machine on the Linux machine? How do I let the Linux know where the private keys are located.

Comment: Try copying the key files to the appropriate location on the VM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume you have VMware Tools installed in your VM: select your key file in Windows Explorer, copy it to clipboard, switch to VM and paste it.

Move it to ~/.ssh/ (if directory not present, create it with mkdir; it's hidden by default, so make sure to enable Show Hidden Files in Gnome File Explorer, or use ls -alF in terminal), rename it to id_rsa.

Enforce key file's permission: chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa (IMPORTANT, otherwise Linux would refuse to use this key file)

Okay you're all set. All commands will use your key file by default.

Comment: The `~..ssh` directory should also be unreadable by others (`chmod 700 ~/.ssh`

Comment: @xenoid I tried on Ubuntu 16.04 and macOS, setting ~/.ssh 0755 and ssh does not seem to complain. If ~/.ssh is created automatically by sshd, it will be 0700, indeed.